# Need help! I can't connect my program in oracle 11g using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, codeigniter, oracle11g

I have a program created using mysql and soon will e migrated to oracle 11g database. My problem is my page always 'Not Found' even if I already set up all the changes in my config.php and database.php

Here's my code

config.php

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://192.168.0.112:1521/testing/';`

or

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://192.168.0.112/testing/';`

I also tried to add index.php on the url

database.php

```
$active_group = 'oracle';
$active_record = TRUE;

$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.112)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';
//112
$db['oracle']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['oracle']['username'] = 'sample';
$db['oracle']['password'] = 'samplepass';
$db['oracle']['database'] = 'test';

$db['oracle']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['oracle']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['oracle']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['oracle']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['oracle']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['oracle']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['oracle']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['oracle']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Please don't mark it as duplicate I haven't found solutions on other questions here. I tried to refer to some links, but still not working.

Output:

Not Found

The requested URL /testing/index was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.0.112 Port 80

Comment: An error for requested URL not found is not caused by DB connection issues but has to do with routing and or .htaccess

Comment: But I think there's something wrong on my set up. Maybe the way I call it on config.php. I dont know.

Comment: I'm sure there is something wrong with your setup but it is most likely in your routes or .htaccess as the error is not DB related. What is in your .htaccess, routes.php, controller that should handle this request ?

Answer (score 1):

change from

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://192.168.0.112/testing/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

and also change from

```
$active_group = 'oracle';
$active_record = TRUE;

$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.112)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';
//112
$db['oracle']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['oracle']['username'] = 'sample';
$db['oracle']['password'] = 'samplepass';
$db['oracle']['database'] = 'test';

$db['oracle']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['oracle']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['oracle']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['oracle']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['oracle']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['oracle']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['oracle']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['oracle']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

//112
$db['default']['hostname'] = 192.168.0.112;
$db['default']['username'] = 'sample';
$db['default']['password'] = 'samplepass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I received A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: Do it have any differences on calling a database query like $this->db->get_where('user_tbl', array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>md5($password)));

Comment: in autoload.php file put the following code                               $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'Freakauth_light');

Comment: in autoload.php file place $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'Freakauth_light');

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: freakauth_light ... I believe its $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103829/discussion-between-dhruv-jadia-and-jned29).